# Bulk Download via Google App Engine Backend

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bulkloader

I have 1.6 Million entities in a Google App Engine app that I would like to download. I tried using the built in bulkloader mechanism but found that it is terribly slow. While I can only download ~30 entities/second via the bulkloader, I can do ~500 entities/second by querying the datastore via a backend. A backend is necessary to circumvent the 60 second request limit. In addition, datastore queries can only live for up to 30 seconds so you need to break up your fetches across multiple queries using query cursors.

The code on the server side fetches an 1000 entities and returns a query cursor:

```
cursor = request.get('cursor')
devices = Pushdev.all()

if (cursor and cursor!=''):
    devices.with_cursor(cursor)

next1000 = devices.fetch(1000)

for d in next1000:
    t = int(time.mktime(d.created.timetuple()))
    response.out.write('%s/%s/%d\n'%(d.name,d.alias,t))

response.out.write(devices.cursor())
```

On the client side, I have a loop that invokes the handler on the server with a null cursor to begin with and then starts to pass the cursor received by the previous invocation. It terminates when it gets an empty result.

PROBLEM: I am only able to fetch a fraction - ~20% of the entities using this method. I get a response with empty data even though the full set of entities has not been traversed. Why does this method not fetch everything comprehensively?

Comment: Could you be hitting your daily budget from read ops?

Comment: Nope. This is a premium account.

Comment: You still set a daily budget of how much you're willing to pay.

Comment: While that seems like it should be the logical behavior, in practice when you transfer an app into a premium account the "Billing Settings" tab empties out, and AFAIK you can no longer set daily or weekly caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything to confirm or deny this in the docs, but my guess is that `all()` has a non-deterministic ordering such that eventually one of your `fetch(1000)`'s will hit the "last element" and `devices.cursor()` will return nothing.

Try this:

```
devices = Pushdev.all().order('__key__')
```

Comment: This was it. I haven't tested thoroughly yet. Will do and post any updates.